# How can I rewrite the From: address of an email and resend it?

Tags: scripting, email

I have a cPanel web hosting account. On this account I have a PHP-based support/trouble ticket system for my customers to use. I'd like to be able to send an email to both my customer and to the ticket system, but have the email that goes to the ticketing system appear to come *from* my customer, so that the support ticket which gets created appears under their account.

So what I want to do is create some email address `billing-redirect@mydomain.com` which gets piped to a unix command or shell script. This means that when I send an email from `billing@mydomain.com` to `some_customer@example.com` and CC `billing-redirect@mydomain.com`, the shell script should be able to *resend* the email to `support@mydomain.com` **but resend the email from the To: address of the email**.

Is there any way to make a shell script which will accept an email on stdin, rewrite the From: address, and resend the mail to a new address? Can Procmail do anything like that? Or will I have to hand code this myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Procmail comes with the [`formail`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=formail&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE+and+Ports) command to manipulate mail headers. The [`procmailex`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=procmailex&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE+and+Ports) contains examples of uses in `.procmailrc`. This should do what you want (untested):

```
formail -R To: From: -U From: -I Cc: -I 'To: support@mydomain.com'
```

Comment: This is close... it's rewriting the "To:" line but not the "From:". I think it can get me there though!

Comment: @Josh Weird, it works for me: `From: billing To: customer Cc: redirect` turns into `From: customer To: support@mydomain.com`. Procmail 3.22 (Debian lenny).

Comment: Probably a bug in my version of procmail. `procmail v3.22` on `CentOS release 5.8`

Answer (score 1):

Gilles' answer was almost there, but for some reason I had to pipe through `formail` *twice*. In addition, I needed to actually send the mail after rewriting the headers. Here's what I did to make this whole thing work:

1. I created a new file `~/bin/resend-support` containing:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   /usr/bin/formail -R To: From: | \
     /usr/bin/formail -U From: -I Cc: -I 'To: support@mydomain.com' | \
     /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t
   ```
2. I made the file executable (`chmod +x ~/bin/resend-support`)
3. In cPanel, I created an email address forwarder `resend-support@mydomain.com` which piped to `~/bin/resend-support` (using "Pipe to a program" under "Advanced")

Now, when I send an email to `someone@example.com` and CC `resend-support@mydomain.com`, it gets piped to `~/bin/resend-support` which resends the email to `support@mydomain.com` *from* `someone@example.com`